# JSoup parsing HTML

Tags: java, android, html-parsing, jsoup

I am trying to parse a non well formed DTD html file which i retrieve by a inputstream with JSOUP, and get all the data in the TD fields.
How can i do that with JSoup?
I already looked at the http://jsoup.org/cookbook/ but i should need som example to get it started.

Thank you in advance.

I already tried the saxparser but i can`t get the DTD to work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-             strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="nl" lang="nl"> 
<TABLE class=personaltable cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0> 
 <TBODY> 
  <TR class=alternativerow> 
   <TD>Nieuw beltegoed:</TD> 
   <TD>€ 1,00</TD></TR> 
  <TR> 
   <TD>Tegoed vorige periode:  
   <TD>€ 2,00</TD></TD></TR> 
  <TR class=alternativerow> 
   <TD>Tegoed tot 09-11-2011:  
   <TD>€ 10,00</TD></TD></TR> 
  <TR> 
   <TD> 
   <TD height=25></TD> 
  <TR class=alternativerow> 
   <TD>Verbruik sinds nieuw tegoed:</TD> 
   <TD>€ 0,33</TD></TR> 
  <TR> 
   <TD>Ongebruikt tegoed:</TD> 
   <TD>€ 12,00</TD></TR> 
  <TR class=alternativerow> 
   <TD class=f-Orange>Verbruik boven bundel:</TD> 
   <TD class=f-Orange>€ 0,00</TD></TR> 
  <TR> 
   <TD>Verbruik dat niet in de bundel zit*:</TD> 
   <TD>€ 0,00</TD></TR> 
  </TBODY> 
 </TABLE> 
</html>
```

Edit:
I am getting a force close, i need the JSoup in my AsyncTask.
Here is the LOgcat:

```
10-20 21:07:36.679: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1396): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-20 21:07:36.679: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1396): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-20 21:07:36.679: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1396):     at   com.sencide.AndroidLogin$MyTask.onPostExecute(AndroidLogin.java:276)
10-20 21:07:36.679: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1396):     at com.sencide.AndroidLogin$MyTask.onPostExecute(AndroidLogin.java:1)
10-20 21:07:36.679: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1396):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
10-20 21:07:36.679: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1396):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
10-20 21:07:36.679: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1396):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
10-20 21:07:36.679: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1396):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-20 21:07:36.679: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1396):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
10-20 21:07:36.679: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1396):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
10-20 21:07:36.679: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1396):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-20 21:07:36.679: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1396):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-20 21:07:36.679: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1396):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
10-20 21:07:36.679: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1396):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
10-20 21:07:36.679: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1396):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the AsyncTask code:

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    private Elements tdsFromSecondColumn=null;
}

protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
      InputStream inputStreamActivity = response.getEntity().getContent();

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStreamActivity));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }

                /******* CLOSE CONNECTION AND STREAM *******/

                System.out.println(sb);
                inputStreamActivity.close();

                String kpn;
                kpn = sb.toString();

                Document doc = Jsoup.parse(kpn);
                Elements tdsFromSecondColumn = doc.select("table.personaltable td:eq(1)");
}

@Override 
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) { 
        //publishProgress(false); 
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lbl_top);

        for (Element tdFromSecondColumn : tdsFromSecondColumn) { 
            //System.out.println(tdFromSecondColumn.text()); 
            tv.setText("");
            tv.setText(tdFromSecondColumn.text());
        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, you have an `InputStream` and not an URL? You should then use the [`Jsoup#parse()`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#parse%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method which takes an `InputStream`:

```java
Document document = Jsoup.parse(inputStream, charsetName, baseUri);
// ...
```

The `charsetName` should be the charset the document is originally encoded in. You can leave it `null` to let Jsoup decide or fallback to UTF-8. The `baseUri` should be the URL from which the HTML was originally served. You can leave it `null`, you'll only not be able to resolve relative links.

But if you actually have the original URL, then you could also just use `Jsoup#connect()`:

```java
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
// ...
```

Regardless of the way you obtained the `Document`, you can use [CSS selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) to select elements of interest in the document. See also the [Jsoup cookbook on that subject](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax). Here's an example which extracts all the data from the 2nd column of the `<table>` with a class name of `personaltable`:

```java
Elements tdsFromSecondColumn = document.select("table.personaltable td:eq(1)");

for (Element tdFromSecondColumn : tdsFromSecondColumn) {
    System.out.println(tdFromSecondColumn.text());
}
```

which results in:

```
€ 1,00
€ 2,00
€ 10,00

€ 0,33
€ 12,00
€ 0,00
€ 0,00
```

Comment: Hi BalusC,
Thank you very much for your answer, i will try it right away when i return from work.
I got another questions, is there a way to search for a string like "Nieuw" in the TD elements, and then do something like tv.setText ("Nieuw beltegoed: " + tdFromSecondColumn.text());
Thank you in advance

Comment: You can use the `:contains()` pseudo selector: `document.select("table.personaltable td:contains('Nieuw')")`. See also the Jsoup cookbook on the subject: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax.

Comment: Hi BalusC,
Thx works ok but i have the JSoup in a AsyncTask, i am getting a force close.
I edited my code with the Logcat and AsyncTask code.
Do you have time to help?
Thx in advance.

Comment: It gives a runtime exception when I leave baseUri as null.

Comment: The documentation here https://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/load-document-from-file says that it can be left as empty string, not null.